# write / append to very large csv with panda's to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory

I am opening one very large csv in chunks using pandas read_csv with a chunksize set because the csv is too large to fit into memory.  I am performing transformations on each chunk.  I then want to append the transformed df chunk to the end another existing (and very large) csv.

I have been running into out-of-memory errors though.  Does pandas to_csv(mode='a', header=False) open the csv in order to append the new chunk?  In other words, is the to_csv() causing my memory errors?

Comment: It would need to open it by definition. That said, merely opening the file shouldn't cause memory errors if you don't read it in. Post a [MCVE]; odds are you're probably holding onto data longer than you think, or loading larger chinks of data than you think.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue several times. What you might try is to export your data chunks in several csv (without headers) and then concatenate them with a non pandas function (e.g. Writing new lines on a text file read from your different csv)